# How to block the traffic served from WSO2 API gateway and allow only from on-premises gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway, ibm-api-management

The World Bank API is created in API Cloud and it can be invoked from API Console as well as from curl command through on-premises gateway.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/xml' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 942967aa-9e7f-3c4b-823e-87da7cf6e6ee' 'https://localhost:8243/t/devmr/wb/1.0.0/countries/usa' -k
```

What is the recommended practice to make sure that consumer applications can invoke only through on-premises gateway?

Comment: Does API Cloud offer any IP based restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access to your API based on IP address. You can white label the ip address of on-premises gateway and allow access from only that ip address as described in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/white-listing-ips-in-wso2-api-manager). This article speaks about WSO2 API Manager, you can do this in API Cloud as well.